# Working with video in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, video

I have small Movie clips that needs to be played, throughout the game i am making. Currently i am making them in aftereffets and exporting them as FLV files and embedding them into timeline, making a moviclip symbol to play them.

But that obviously is a disaster. This way i get very small movie clips but they don't garbage collect at all. So it keeps getting stored in the memory. if I turn them into SWF, the files become like 10 times bigger, going as high as 24 mb for 2.4 mb flv file. It's really frustrating to work with it this way.

Can somebody please suggest a way to work with videos/clips in actionscript 3? I don't need any controls for these movie clips, they serve as cut scenes.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe introduced [StageVideo](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage_video.html), leveraging hardware acceleration for high performance video playback.

> To mitigate the performance impact of rendering video in the Video
>   object, Adobe has introduced stage video as a new way to render video.
>   This approach takes full advantage of the underlying video hardware.
>   The result is a much lower load on the CPU, which translates into
>   higher frame rates on less powerful devices and also less memory
>   usage.

[Example implementation from Thibault Imbert](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage_video.html):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.FullScreenEvent;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.events.StageVideoAvailabilityEvent;
    import flash.events.StageVideoEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.events.VideoEvent;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.media.SoundTransform;
    import flash.media.StageVideo;
    import flash.media.StageVideoAvailability;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.system.LoaderContext;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    /**
     * 
     * @author Thibault Imbert
     * 
     */ 
    [SWF(frameRate="1", backgroundColor="#000000")]
    public class SimpleStageVideo extends Sprite
    {
        private static const FILE_NAME:String = "video-file.mov";
        private static const INTERVAL:Number = 500;
        private static const BORDER:Number = 20;

        private var legend:TextField = new TextField();
        private var sv:StageVideo;
        private var nc:NetConnection;
        private var ns:NetStream;
        private var rc:Rectangle;
        private var video:Video;
        private var thumb:Shape;
        private var interactiveThumb:Sprite;
        private var totalTime:Number;

        private var videoWidth:int;
        private var videoHeight:int;
        private var outputBuffer:String = new String();
        private var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, BORDER);
        private var videoRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        private var gotStage:Boolean;
        private var stageVideoInUse:Boolean;
        private var classicVideoInUse:Boolean;
        private var accelerationType:String;
        private var infos:String = new String();
        private var available:Boolean;
        private var inited:Boolean;
        private var played:Boolean;
        private var container:Sprite;

        /**
         * 
         * 
         */     
        public function SimpleStageVideo()
        {
            // Make sure the app is visible and stage available
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
        {
            // Scaling
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            legend.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

            // Debug infos
            legend.multiline = true;
            legend.background = true;
            legend.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            addChild(legend);

            // Thumb seek Bar
            thumb = new Shape();

            interactiveThumb = new Sprite();
            interactiveThumb.addChild(thumb);
            addChild(interactiveThumb);

            // Connections
            nc = new NetConnection();
            nc.connect(null);
            ns = new NetStream(nc);
            ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
            ns.client = this;

            // Screen
            video = new Video();
            video.smoothing = true;

            // Video Events
            // the StageVideoEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_STATE informs you if StageVideo is available or not
            stage.addEventListener(StageVideoAvailabilityEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_AVAILABILITY, onStageVideoState);
            // in case of fallback to Video, we listen to the VideoEvent.RENDER_STATE event to handle resize properly and know about the acceleration mode running
            video.addEventListener(VideoEvent.RENDER_STATE, videoStateChange);

            // Input Events
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE,  onResize);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function onNetStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void
        {
            if ( event.info == "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound" )
                legend.text = "Video file passed, not available!";
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function onFrame(event:Event):void 
        {
            var ratio:Number = (ns.time / totalTime) * (stage.stageWidth - (BORDER << 1));
            rect.width = ratio;
            thumb.graphics.clear();
            thumb.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
            thumb.graphics.drawRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);   
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if ( event.stageY >= interactiveThumb.y - BORDER && event.stageX <= stage.stageWidth - BORDER )
            {
                var seekTime:Number = (stage.mouseX - BORDER) * ( totalTime / (stage.stageWidth - (BORDER << 1) ) );
                ns.seek( seekTime );    
            }
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {   
            if ( event.keyCode == Keyboard.O )
            {
                if ( available )
                    // We toggle the StageVideo on and off (fallback to Video and back to StageVideo)
                    toggleStageVideo(inited=!inited);

            } else if ( event.keyCode == Keyboard.F )
            {
                stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
            } else if ( event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE )
            {
                ns.togglePause();
            }
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param width
         * @param height
         * @return 
         * 
         */     
        private function getVideoRect(width:uint, height:uint):Rectangle
        {   
            var videoWidth:uint = width;
            var videoHeight:uint = height;
            var scaling:Number = Math.min ( stage.stageWidth / videoWidth, stage.stageHeight / videoHeight );

            videoWidth *= scaling, videoHeight *= scaling;

            var posX:uint = stage.stageWidth - videoWidth >> 1;
            var posY:uint = stage.stageHeight - videoHeight >> 1;

            videoRect.x = posX;
            videoRect.y = posY;
            videoRect.width = videoWidth;
            videoRect.height = videoHeight;

            return videoRect;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * 
         */     
        private function resize ():void
        {   
            if ( stageVideoInUse )
            {
                // Get the Viewport viewable rectangle
                rc = getVideoRect(sv.videoWidth, sv.videoHeight);
                // set the StageVideo size using the viewPort property
                sv.viewPort = rc;
            } else 
            {
                // Get the Viewport viewable rectangle
                rc = getVideoRect(video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
                // Set the Video object size
                video.width = rc.width;
                video.height = rc.height;
                video.x = rc.x, video.y = rc.y;
            }

            interactiveThumb.x = BORDER, interactiveThumb.y = stage.stageHeight - (BORDER << 1);
            legend.text = infos;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param evt
         * 
         */     
        public function onMetaData ( evt:Object ):void
        {
            totalTime = evt.duration;
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function onStageVideoState(event:StageVideoAvailabilityEvent):void
        {   
            // Detect if StageVideo is available and decide what to do in toggleStageVideo
            toggleStageVideo(available = inited = (event.availability == StageVideoAvailability.AVAILABLE));
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param on
         * 
         */     
        private function toggleStageVideo(on:Boolean):void
        {   
            infos = "StageVideo Running (Direct path) : " + on + "\n";

            // If we choose StageVideo we attach the NetStream to StageVideo
            if (on) 
            {
                stageVideoInUse = true;
                if ( sv == null )
                {
                    sv = stage.stageVideos[0];
                    sv.addEventListener(StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE, stageVideoStateChange);
                }
                sv.attachNetStream(ns);
                if (classicVideoInUse)
                {
                    // If we use StageVideo, we just remove from the display list the Video object to avoid covering the StageVideo object (always in the background)
                    stage.removeChild ( video );
                    classicVideoInUse = false;
                }
            } else 
            {
                // Otherwise we attach it to a Video object
                if (stageVideoInUse)
                    stageVideoInUse = false;
                classicVideoInUse = true;
                video.attachNetStream(ns);
                stage.addChildAt(video, 0);
            }

            if ( !played ) 
            {
                played = true;
                ns.play(FILE_NAME);
            }
        } 

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function onResize(event:Event):void
        {
            resize();       
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function stageVideoStateChange(event:StageVideoEvent):void
        {   
            infos += "StageVideoEvent received\n";
            infos += "Render State : " + event.status + "\n";
            resize();
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function videoStateChange(event:VideoEvent):void
        {   
            infos += "VideoEvent received\n";
            infos += "Render State : " + event.status + "\n";
            resize();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I read about it, and I went through the code, but it's little difficult to understand since I am just starting out. Can u please be so kind and highlight the portions i should focus on for getting the video on to the stage?

Comment: Use this _SimpleStageVideo_ class as a utility, simply: `var stageVideo:SimpleStageVideo = new StageVideo(); addChild(stageVideo);`.  Set the `FILE_NAME` string to the path of your video.  For reuse, I change FILE_NAME to a variable.  In Flash Pro, this could be converted to a component, in which the file name is set as a property by marking the file name variable as `[Inspectable]`.  [CS6 FLA Example](http://www.jasonsturges.com/labs/stack-overflow/examples/stage-video/StageVideo.zip) of [SWF](http://www.jasonsturges.com/labs/stack-overflow/examples/stage-video/StageVideo.swf).